# Need help choosing a power supply for a breadboard

Tags: power-supply, voltage, power, breadboard

Hey i want to (in the long term) start experimenting with remaking modules from old analog synthesizers. For example remake an oscillator from a Minimoog or a chorus from a Roland Juno-60 or something for my own pleasure.

And i figured that i would just start out by experimenting on a breadboard. But i have never used a breadboard so i don't know that much about them. I know how it works when there is power put into it. But i don't know how to power it. I can only really find power supplies that supply 3,3/5V and that is too small a voltage for what i want to do. I think i need something that is variable and that can at least output 30V. It is important that it can send out different voltage and that it can be used with a MB102 breadboard.

What could be a good solution for me?

If you have any tips for using a breadboard for something like this or if you just have some tips in general then it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in forward

Comment: Any bench PSU will do

Answer (score 2):

You will want to invest in a "lab power supply" or "benchtop power supply" which is typically a single or dual channel adjustable supply, such as this one:

https://www.sra-solder.com/korad-ka3005d-precision-variable-adjustable-30v-5a-dc-linear-power-supply-digital-regulated-lab-grade

They come with cables that have a banana plug on one end and an alligator clip on the other. You can strip a short piece of wire to go between the hole in your breadboard and the alligator clip to provide power easily.

Bigger breadboards have binding posts which is a round connector you can use for power, that also accepts a banana plug. That way you can use a cable with banana plugs on both ends to conveniently route power from your power supply to the large bread board. Here's an example of one:

https://www.adafruit.com/product/443

For your application you may want to pick a power supply that can provide the maximum voltage you need (say 30V) and then add voltage regulators on the breadboard to provide lower voltages as needed, such as 5V or 12V that are derived from the 30V source.

Comment: I am in europe so could something like this do the trick? https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/DC-Bench-Power-Supply-30V-5A-Variable-Precision-Adjustable-Digital-Lab-Grade/223112987333?epid=4020400842&hash=item33f29202c5:g:BEQAAOSwMn1bdDPV

Comment: or this: https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/30V-5A-Adjustable-DC-Power-Supply-Precision-Variable-Digital-Lab-Test-w-Cable/312186146067

Comment: Yep, either one will work. All lab power supplies perform the same basic function and only differ in their maximum ratings (in the ones you linked, 30V/5A max) and their user interface. Ideally I'd suggest getting one that has good user reviews too.

Answer (score 1):

> What could be a good solution for me?

1. Choose a circuit that you wish to build.
2. Examine the schematic to find the voltages required to power the circuit.
3. Estimate the maximum current drawn by the circuit.
4. Find one or more mains powered power supplies with the required output voltages and adequate current rating. This might be a split rail ±15 V supply for a synthesizer module or a 9 V supply for a guitar effects unit. Variable power supplies are very useful for the experimenter but more expensive - especially the split-rail type.
5. The breadboards have power rails along the edges - usually two on each side. Normal practice would be to have a GND (ground or 0 V) rail on each side and positive on one side and negative on the other.

Answer (score 0):

I would build my own power supply for this because it would be a lot cheaper than a lab power supply and it would meet my custom requirements.

I would start with a wall adapter that provides two isolated voltages (from a transformer with two secondaries) that provides a few extra volts more than what I need to compensate for the drop on the regulators. The two secondaries are necesary for a symmetrical power supply, which is probably what you want so that you don't have nasty offset resistors and stuff like that.

If I needed fixed regulated voltages, I would use LM7812 and LM7912 for +-12 V. For and adjustable power supply I would use LM317 and LM337.

I would build the whole thing on a perf board so that it plugs right into the power rails of the breadboard using pin headers to power the rails and screw terminals for the inputs from the wall adapter.

I would also avoid switching mode power supplies because they might add high frequency ripple. Linear regulators would be a good choice for such a project.

Anyways, the project idea sounds really nice to me and I've played with similar things myself. Good luck.